# C print a generic type vector

Tags: c, vector, printf

Hi I'm trying to create a function that takes a void* pointer as parameter and print all element of the vector using printf

the declaration of the function is:

```
void print_vec(void *vec,int dime_se,int dime,char *format);
```

and implementation is:

```
void print_vec(void *vec,int dime_se,int dime,char *format){
    for(int i=0;i<dime;i++)
        printf(format,*(vec+dime_se*i));
}
```

the problem is that when i compile the compiler returns:

```
error: invalid use of void expression printf(format,*(vec+dime_se*i));
```

So the question there is a way to do this task without make this?

```
void print_vec(void *vec,int dime_se,int dime,char *format){
for(int i=0;i<dime;i++)
    switch(format[1]){
        case 'c':
            printf(format,*((char*)(vec+dime_se*i)));
            break;

        case 'd':
            printf(format,*((unsigned int*)(vec+dime_se*i)));
            break;


        case 's':
            printf(format,*((char**)(vec+dime_se*i)));
            break;

        case 'i':
            printf(format,*((int*)(vec+dime_se*i)));
            break;



        case 'f':
            printf(format,*((float*)(vec+dime_se*i)));
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

}

Comment: no. C have not generic types. to call `printf`with valid arguments compiler need extra information about size of arguments. in your example you use `int`, `char`, `float` and `char*` and they can have any size depends on your machine

Comment: Pointer math on `void*` is not portable.  `(unsigned int*)(vec+dime_se*i)` --> `((unsigned int*)vec + i)`

Comment: Why use `'d'` with `unsigned`?  `'d'` goes with  `int`.  `'u'` goes with  `unsigned`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `dime_se` param. The size is more or less implicit in the format character.
Also, if you cast to the right pointer type you can let C do the scaling instead of doing it
manually:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void print_vec(void const*vec,size_t dime,char const*format)
{
    for(size_t i=0;i<dime;i++)
        switch(format[1]){
            #define X(Char,Tp) break;case Char: printf(format,((Tp*)vec)[i])
            X('c',char);
            X('d',unsigned);
            X('s',char*);
            X('i',int);
            X('f',float);
            break;default: return;
            #undef X
        }
}
```

I said more or less because type promotion kind of blurs the line. `%f` could well mean you've got a `double` instead of a `float`.

If you want to use a `dime_se` parameter to disambiguate that case, you can:

```
         break;case 'f': 
                if(sizeof(double)==dime_se)
                     printf(format,((double*)vec)[i]);
                else { 
                     assert(sizeof(float)==dime_se); 
                     printf(format,((float*)vec)[i]); 
                }
```

but I'm not sure if a `print_vec` function like that is a good idea.

Comment: Note this answer will only work if your format string always start with a simple type like %d.
If you want the function to do fancier printing like fixed number of decimals "%.02f", or print an entire message for each item in the vector, you would need a more complex parsing logic to rely on the format string for typing.

Comment: @chux Missed that. Thanks.

Comment: As coded, printing any `'f'` returns right after printing (drop through) .  Curious: why `#define X(Char,Tp) break;case Char: printf(format,((Tp*)vec)[i])` and not `#define X(Char,Tp) case Char: printf(format,((Tp*)vec)[i]); break` ?

Comment: @chux It's just how I write my switches if they contain mostly "breaking-cases". It doesn't matter with the macro, but in normal C code, if I see each `case` preceded by `break;` it'll make one that isn't stand out more easily than if the `break` were at the end of what follows the `case`. It helps me quickly catch accidental fall-through. I think it's pretty neat that the C grammar allows me to symmetrically start even the first `case` with `break` even though the `break` part is basically dead code there.

Comment: Hmmm, If you value `break` at the beginning, perhaps then `#define X(Char,Tp) break;case Char: printf(format,((Tp*)vec)[i]); break` to avoid the earlier coding oops that caused a "accidental fall-through".